# Set CSS style to GtkBox with python

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pygtk

is posible change the background color of an object GtkBox? so far all the styles I have worked well in other objects but GtkBox not work for me  You know why? this is my code

```
self.Ventana = self.builder.get_object("ventana")
self.Header= self.builder.get_object("header")
self.Ventana.set_name('MyWindow')
self.Header.set_name('header')
self.style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
self.css=open(self.ruta+'/css/estilos.css','rb')
self.css_data = self.css.read()
self.style_provider.load_from_data(self.css_data)
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(),self.style_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

/*********CSS STYLES *********/
#MyWindow {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
/*i try whit: #MyWindow #header, #MyWindow GtkBox */
#header{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that not all gtk widgets draw their own background. The background is then determined by the underlying widget. This behavior was changed for [some widgets](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.12/developers.html.en) with gtk+ 3.12.

So changing the background color of a Gtk.Box does not work for **version < gtk+ 3.12**. If you are using an older version, an alternative approach would be to use a Gtk.Viewport underneath the Gtk.Box and change the color of the viewport.

To put it into some code:

```
box = Gtk.Box()
viewport = Gtk.Viewport()
viewport.add(box)
#and the CssProvder, StyleContext,...
```

CSS:

```
GtkViewport {
    background-color: red;
)
```